# Is there a linker script directive that allows me to move my stack start address?

Tags: linker, executable, elf, linker-scripts, executable-format

I'm trying to change the start location of my stack using a linker script on x86_64.
I was able to move my executable start address using this:

```
PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x200000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x200000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
```

I changed my globals like this:

```
 .data ALIGN(0x10000000)           :
{
*(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
 SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
}
```

I tried to use the following for moving the stack region:

```
. = 0x50000000;
.stack    :
{
 stack_start = .;

  PROVIDE( stack_start = . );
  *(.stack)
      . += 0x2000;
  stack_end = . ;
  PROVIDE( stack_end = . );
}
```

But that didn't get me anywhere.

Here is the test program that I use to test my stack location:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int global_var = 555;

void test()
{
   int local_test = 666;

   printf("address of global_var: %p\n", &global_var);
   printf("address of local_test: %p\n", &local_test);

}

int main()
{
   int local_main = 5;
   printf("address of local_main: %p\n", &local_main);
   printf("address of test(): %p\n", &test);
   printf("address of main(): %p\n", &main);
   test();
   return 0;
}
```

This is my output from gcc's default linker script(no modifications):

```
address of local_main: 0x7fffffffe26c  <---- I want to move local vars
address of test(): 0x40050c
address of main(): 0x400547
address of global_var: 0x600a10
address of local_test: 0x7fffffffe24c <----  I want to move local vars
```

Here is the output from my linker script:

```
address of local_main: 0x7fffffffe26c   <--- unchanged
address of test(): 0x2005ac
address of main(): 0x2005e7
address of global_var: 0x10000010
address of local_test: 0x7fffffffe24c   <--- unchanged
```

I am really confused since nm outputs new locations:

```
 $ nm -n test.out
             w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
             w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
             w _Jv_RegisterClasses
             w __gmon_start__
             U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
             U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000200460 T _init
00000000002004a0 T _start
00000000002004cc t call_gmon_start
00000000002004f0 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000200520 t register_tm_clones
0000000000200560 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200580 t frame_dummy
00000000002005ac T test
00000000002005e7 T main
0000000000200650 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000200660 T __libc_csu_init
00000000002006ec T _fini
00000000002006f8 R _IO_stdin_used
0000000000200870 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000400878 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000400878 t __init_array_start
0000000000400880 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000400880 t __init_array_end
0000000000400888 d __JCR_END__
0000000000400888 d __JCR_LIST__
0000000000400890 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000400a78 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000010000000 D __data_start
0000000010000000 W data_start
0000000010000008 D __dso_handle
0000000010000010 D global_var
0000000010000018 D __TMC_END__
0000000020000000 A __bss_start
0000000020000000 A _edata
0000000020000000 b completed.6092
0000000050000000 B stack_start
0000000050002000 A _end
0000000050002000 B stack_end
```

Though I'm not even sure if stack_start and stack_end are valid on x86_64, since I got that part off of linker script tutorial for arm online. I get no errors or warnings with my linker script, so I'm not sure what's going on.

In case you are wondering why would anyone do this - it has implications for security research.

Is there a way to do what I want using linker scripts? I just can't believe that I can move my .text, .bss and .data sections, but not the stack.

---

**Update:** Here is an explanation taken from http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html#os on why this is not doable with a linker:

> "You may have noticed that all of the discussion of object files and
>   linkers so far has only talked about global variables; there's been no
>   mention of the local variables and dynamically allocated memory
>   mentioned earlier.These pieces of data don't need any linker
>   involvement, because their lifetime only occurs when the program is
>   running—long after the linker has finished its business."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a linker script directive that allows me to move my stack start address?

On Linux (which you appear to be using): no.

The stack location on Linux is determined by the kernel, and the current value of `ulimit -s`; it is *not* encoded in any way into the main executable.

> In case you are wondering why would anyone do this - it has implications for security research.

If you want to explicitly control stack location, you'll have to write a custom `ELF` loader that would `mmap()` and set up stack the way kernel does (and the way glibc expects it to be set up), then transfer control to `a.out` or `ld-linux`.

> What about Windows?

It has been a long time since I touched Windows, but I believe the situation there is similar -- the kernel determines stack location.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My own findings are moving in that direction too. It's nice to have someone else confirm my understanding. Just curious, do you know if there is a way to do this on Windows, since your answer was focused on Linux? I am focusing on Linux though, so your answer applies 100%.

Comment: Another follow up question I have is how would ulimit -s help with varying the stack location, since the -s just controls the stack size?

Comment: @IvanAlagenchev I've updated the answer. Re: `ulimit -s` -- I mis-remembered. It doesn't in fact help.